# How to change emission color behind glass? (Cycles)

Tags: glass, emission

How can one maintain the color of the emission even after placing glass in front of it?

[image]

[image]

Node set up for the sphere

[image]

Comment: The problem is, the _Mix Shader_ depends on the _Is Camera Ray_ output. But this always refers to rays directly between the camera and the object's surface. Now that you've put glass around it, _Is Transmission Ray_ is the one which does what you want. However, the emission shining on objects that lie outside the glass cube will then be yellow.

Comment: This may be easier to do in the compositor with separate view layers

Comment: @Gorgious definitely yes.